# How to only import sub module without exec __init__.py in the package

Tags: python, import, module, package

When import sub module from a package, the __init__.py file in the package folder will be exec first, how can I disable this. Sometimes I only need one function in a package, import the whole package is a little heavy.

For example the `pandas.io.clipboard` module doesn't dependent on any other functions in pandas.

`from pandas.io.clipboard import clipboard_get` will import the function, but also import all the pandas common modules. Are there some method that just import the clipboard module, as it's a module in my own application folder.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question generally but you could use [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) instead of the pandas clipboard module.

Answer (score 18):

No there isn't, *by design*. If you want to avoid much overhead when import sub-modules you just use empty `__init__.py`s to define the packages. In this way the overhead of importing the package is practically zero.

If `pandas` does *not* do that you have *no* way to import `pandas.io.clipboard` without importing `pandas` and `io` first. What you *can* do, however it's a huge *hack* and it is **not** equivalent, is to import the `clipboard` module as a normal module instead of as a sub-module. You simply have to find the location where `pandas` is installed (e.g. `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages/`) and insert the path of the parent package in the `sys.path` (`/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages/pandas/io` in your case). Then you can import the `clipboard` package by doing:

```
import clipboard
```

Note however that:

```
import clipboard
from pandas.io import clipboard as clipboard2
print(clipboard == clipboard2)
```

Will print `False`. In fact doing this can break a lot of code, since you are fundamentally breaking some invariants that the `import` mechanism assumes.

In particular if the sub-module *does* reference other sub-modules using relative imports the import will fail, and there are other situations where it will not behave correctly. An other example where this fails is if you have to deal with pickled objects. If you have some objects pickled using the module imported as `pandas.io.clipboard` you will **not** be able to unpickle them using the module `clipboard` imported as above.

In summary, **don't**! I suggest to either:

- Live with it if the time taken to import the package it's not a *real* issue.
- Or: Try to search for a replacement. If you need only `pandas.io.clipboard` but not the rest of `pandas` maybe you shouldn't use `pandas` in the first place and you should use smaller package that implements only the functionality of `clipboard`.

---

If you look at [`pandas.util.clipboard` source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/clipboard/__init__.py) you find out that it's actually just the [`pyperclip`](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip) module version 1.7. You can just add this module in your `site-packages` and use it instead of the one provided by `pandas`. In fact the `pandas` team only added the following piece at the end of the source code:

```
## pandas aliases
clipboard_get = paste
clipboard_set = copy
```

---

Expanding a bit about *why* python import works this way.

As you know in python *modules are objects*. And it also happens that *packages are modules*, although not every module is a package. When you import a package as in:

```
import pandas.io.clipboard
```

Python has to:

1. Create the `module` instance `pandas`
2. Create the `module` instance `io` and add it as attribute to `pandas`
3. Create the `module` instance `clipboard` and add it as attribute to `io`.

In order to create a `module` instance python *must execute the code* in the module.

The imports of the form:

```
from pandas.io import clipboard
```

Are just syntactic sugar for:

```
import pandas.io.clipboard
clipboard = pandas.io.clipboard
del pandas.io
```

Note that in the `from` case `clipboard` could be either a `module`/package or simply something defined inside `io`. In order to check for this the interpreter *must* also import `io` and to do this it *must* also import `pandas`.

Comment: Is there a way for a package's `__init__.py` to know *how* it was imported? For example, is there a way for panda's `__init__.py` to know it's being loaded from the original statement of `from pandas.util import clipboard` vs. `import pandas`? This would allow package developers to allow importing from specific modules that don't require anything from the rest of the package, for example a `constants.py` module.

Answer (score 5):

I found a method that use `sys.meta_path` to hook the import process:

```
import imp, sys

class DummyLoader(object):

    def load_module(self, name):
        names = name.split("__")
        path = None
        for name in names:
            f, path, info = imp.find_module(name, path)
            path = [path]
        return imp.load_module(name, f, path[0], info)

    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        if "__" in name and not name.startswith("__"):
            return DummyLoader()
        else:
            return None

if not sys.meta_path:
    sys.meta_path.append(DummyLoader())
else:
    sys.meta_path[0] = DummyLoader()
```

Use "__" instead of "." for load the file only:

```
import pandas__util__clipboard as clip
```

or use a function to load the file:

```
import imp

def load_module(name):
    names = name.split(".")
    path = None
    for name in names:
        f, path, info = imp.find_module(name, path)
        path = [path]
    return imp.load_module(name, f, path[0], info)    

clip = load_module("pandas.util.clipboard")
```

Answer (score 4):

With Python3.5+, you can import a source file directly from its path without executing the `__init__` in the directory containing the file. Inspired from the [official importlib example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly):

```py
import importlib
import os
import pathlib
import sys
import types


def import_module_from_path(path: str | os.PathLike) -> types.ModuleType:
  """Import a module from the given path."""
  module_path = pathlib.Path(path).resolve()
  module_name = module_path.stem  # 'path/x.py' -> 'x'
  spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
  module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
  sys.modules[module_name] = module
  spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  return module


# Import `my_module` without executing `/path/to/__init__.py`
my_module = import_module_from_path('/path/to/my_module.py')
```

A few caveats:

- `sys.modules[module_name] = module` will overwrite the module with similar names. Future `import module_name` call will returns this module.
- The file is executed even if it is already imported.

You can check `sys.modules` and add some logic to solve those issues.

Comment: I got `AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'` with this, but solved it with `from importlib import util` and then using `util.spec_from_file_location()` and `util.module_from_spec()`.

Answer (score -2):

I tried these methods but couldn't get them to work. So apparently by design it is not supposed to work..

If you have to do this, create a new branch in the repo from where you are trying to import, or initialise a repo:

```
git checkout -b without_init
```

..then delete out `__init__.py` !

From wherever you are trying to import you can check that Python is on the correct branch like this:

```
import subprocess
print ("Current branch is:", subprocess.check_output(["git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"], shell=True).strip().decode())

>> without_init
```